# Want to convert number like 1.234.567 to 1234.567

Tags: python, numbers, locale

I have numbers like 1.234.567 that don't recognize as number by python and give SyntaxError. What should i do to convert them to float or str?

Comment: If the points mean to separate thousands the correct number for Python syntax would be 1234567. If it means decimal points it isn't a number at all. So what do the points mean?

Comment: In Turkey we use points after every three digit(from right to left) for readability in integers. For example 1.000.000 is 1 million and 1.400 is a thousand and four hundred.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int("1.234.567".replace(".",""))
```

This will convert 1.234.567 into 1234567 which can then be used as an integer.